# Broadcom Wifi Driver Issues ; Can't Understand Errors, Confused

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, macbook, broadcom

*Macbook Air 2017 13", Broadcom bmc4360 rev03 (14e443a0) card*

**Read the Arch Wiki** on Broadcom Wireless and found "*broadcom-wl*" would work. Would *prefer* to use DKMS version, but have tried both unsucessfully.

( PS: Have installed *BOTH* iwd and wpa_supplicant . Would prefer iwd but *neither* are currently working because of driver issues. Mentioned this *in case* there are known issues of either one with my hw.)

Outputs of relevant commands are hard to provide *exactly* , since Arch is not connected to a network so I'd have to copy them by hand, so I have *paraphrased* them.

`ip addr , ip link`
and similar : Only the `lo` shows.

`uname -r : 5.4.98-1-lts`

`lspci -nnk | grep -i -A3 net`: For `kernel moudles` it only shows `bcma` , not `wl` as it probably should, so I feel that the **`wl` driver is for some reason not loaded ?**

`dmesg | grep -i firmware` gives :

```
Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-9b] only partially covers this bridge
platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
```

I believe the *last two outputs* can be useful to people with a *better* understanding of this; I'm *not quite sure* what its trying to tell me and what I can do to fix it. If there are more commands that I can try that will help, please let me know and I will add the outputs ASAP if I'm online !

Some other bg info : I've been installing and configging Arch since last two days after school , have installed and configged to my liking, works with ethernet on my desktop , is prepped for my C and Python development, has no GUI (I have Ubuntu for that). Been doing development in and playing around with GNU/Linux for a year or so now smile This driver was an issue on my Ubuntu install too (from where I'm posting this) but was fixed by following an AskUbuntu forum answer ; by `dpkg`-ing what they call "bcmwl-kernel-source" , basically the same thing.

*Thanks in advance , hope I can fix this.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also asked this at the Arch forums, link [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263644).

Solution posted there by *forum moderator* [*V1del*](https://bbs.archlinux.org/profile.php?id=64676) :

> For the LTS kernel you need to install broadcom-wl-dkms and linux-lts-headers so the modules can be built against the kernel you are using.

That was all that was needed. Once `-lts` headers were installed `dkms` automatically did the magic , and built the `wl` driver for my kernel, and it works on my mac.

Note to others in the same situation : I remove `wpa_supplicant` , `iwd 1.11-2` works well !